# New Navigation Bar Linking Back to Page 1

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

When I use the back button to go out of a question, I am redirected back to page 1. This is annoying because I already looked over the questions on that page.

This is probably because the page does not use `GET` requests for the page number. Is there a reason for this? This did not happen when I was using the old navigation bar.

Comment: New nav is dead, or at least buried very deep. No official update [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) for over a year, and the developer is ignoring any comments trying to ask for updates. IMHO it's waste of time to use it.